# Can I load the Keycloak register page with an already written email on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, keycloak

I am using Keycloak to secure my javascript application and I am using the `init()` method of Keycloak to load it. From my application I want to send invites to email addresses. For example if I send an invite to an email, I want that person to open that invite link and to face the Keycloak register page with his/her email written on the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, `currentUser` gets all the details with the token. KeyCloak is very confusing with loads of features with terrible documentation. We had to use KeyCloak with React for enterprise software and KeyCloak was very problematic if you don't need the realm level features you should consider using something else.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How will I load the Keycloak function so that that email is on the page?